# I have error to compile build android in ionic

Tags: android, ionic3, android-sdk-manager

have a problem when building my ionic app, do not find build tools but in sdk manager I have installed several versions of this, someone knows how I can fix it?

already try to do it with different points proposed as a solution but it does not work–

No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

I tried this but it did not work, someone has a better idea

enter here
`cd ~ / Library / Android / sdk / tools / bin /`
and later
`./sdkmanager “build-tools; 27.0.3”`
and the version that is asking you
if you get something repositories could not loaded
`touch ~ / .android / repositories.cfg`
and again
`./sdkmanager “build-tools; 27.0.3”`

ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.15.0
npm   : 6.4.1
OS    : macOS
Xcode : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected
```

Requirements check results for android:

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.4.1/bin/gradle
(node:1022) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
```

FAILURE:

```
Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

BUILD FAILED


Total time: 2.509 secs
(node:4554) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/user/Desktop/home-made-app-3/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/user/Desktop/home-made-app-3/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:4554) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4554) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Check where your ANDROID_HOME is pointing right now? It is should be something like this.. "export ANDROID_HOME=YourAndroidPath/Android/sdk"
In my case it is "export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk"

Comment: in the bash_profile the routes are established but they do not work in the directory of my application.

I have added export ANDROID_HOME = / Users / user / Library / Android / sdk
in my directory from terminal and the error has been fixed.